# can we pair two different models of TP Link

Tags: networking, router

I have two TP-LINK TL-PA451KIT AV500 one connected to the router (BT Smart Hub), the other connected to a TV. Both units are working. I want to add a third TP Link (TP-Link TL-PA411 AV 500) in the room next door, but I can get this link working. I'm no computer buff, and thought it would be straight forward. Can anyone help?

Comment: How can you verify it's not working? What did you try? I think more information is required for anyone to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have connected the 3rd unit to a TV and checked on the Network devices on my Network via the BT smart manager page online and the TV isn't listed

Comment: You need to assign all three units the same key. I recommend using a laptop and the manufacturer's management software to do this. (You can use another manufacturer's software if you want. They are all controlled the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

In theory this should work.  The most likely reasons for your issues are:

1. You may need to peer the new device with the other 2 devices.
2. You need to ensure you plug it directly into a wall, not into a power
   board (most power boards have some sort of filtering/overload protection
   which hurts performance or stops them from working)
3. The wiring in your place may just not be up to it - If the circuits are
    on different phases, or go through different RCD's or any one of a number
    of things this can impact performance or stop them working altogether.

You might want to start off by swapping one of the existing ones and see if it works - that will rule out any peering problems if it does.  Simply, taking an existing powerline and putting it in the new location would tell you if there is a problem related to the wiring.

Comment: The unit was plugged directly into the wall socket. I have swapped one of the units and this still had no effect. After trying to pair the two different models the power light and the ethernet light remain on( on the 3rd unit)